# Any options for ledger and immutable database?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, blockchain

I am working on an end-of-year project and I would like to investigate the benefit of using a ledger database or immutable against using a full blockchain. In my theory for a certain application, it would be that the ledger database is simpler to use more than a blockchain. I tried to look for some open source ledger database but I can only see 2 options in the search [Amazon QLDB](https://aws.amazon.com/qldb/) and [immudb](https://immudb.io). Maybe I am missing some project? Is the QLDB using immudb as many of the AWS services are using open source?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon QLDB and immudb are independent projects even though the technology behind both projects is similar (e.g. both use Merkle Trees verify the history of records).

The main difference is that immudb is and open-source project released under the Apache-2.0 License which means that you can easily install it in your own environment.

Comment: Thank you. So I see they are two different projects but its good to know since many AWS projects are built on open source.